# Give an example of a function $f$ which has a simple pole at $z=i-3$ with residue $8(i-3)$ and an essential singularity at $z=i$ with residue $6$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Give an example of a function $f$ which has a simple pole at $z=i-3$ with residue $8(i-3)$ and an essential singularity at $z=i$ with residue $6$.

I know that the function $-24/(z+3-i)$ would have a pole at $z=i-3$ with residue $8(i-3)$ but I cannot seem to make this function also have an essential singularity.
Would making this function trigonometric help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Try something of the form
$$f(z)=e^{1/(z-i)^2}+\frac{A}{z-i}+\frac{B}{z-(i-3)}$$
where $A$ and $B$ are complex numbers to be found. The [essential singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity) is given by $e^{1/(z-i)^2}$ which has residue $0$ at $i$ and at $i-3$.

Comment: I see that the last part of that function is where the pole would be however where is the essential singularity?

Comment: In $\exp(1/(z-i)^2)$ that has residue $0$ at $i$

Comment: Recall that $e^{1/w}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(1/w)^k/k!$.

Comment: Is it clear now? Are you able to find $A$ and $B$?

Comment: I found that if B is equal to 8(i-3), this will give me the pole i-3 with residue 8(i-3). However I am struggling to find the residue 6 for the singularity at i.

Comment: What is the residue of $\frac{A}{z-i}$ at $i$? What is the residue of $\frac{B}{z-(i-3)}$ at $i$? What is the residue of $\exp(1/(z−i)^2)$ at $i$?

Comment: must A be 6 to attain the residue 6?

Comment: Yes! Take $A=6$. The residue is the coefficient of $1/(z-i)$.  In $e^{1/(z-i)^2}=\sum_{k\geq 0}(1/(z-i)^2)^k/k!$ the coefficient of $1/(z-i)$ is zero.

Comment: However I understand that if i is to be an essential singularity , then the limit of the function approaching i does not exist. Taking A=6 and B=8(i-3) gives us exp(1/(z−i)2)+6/(z−i)+(8(i-3))/z−(i−3), but the limit of this function as it approaches i does exist. So how does this work?

Comment: Limit formula for higher order poles works at a finite singularity. It does not work at an essential singularity (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles).  $\exp(1/(z−i)^2)+6/(z−i)+(8(i-3))/(z−(i−3))$ is fine and it is analytic in the complex plane minus $i$ and $i-3$.

Comment: Any further doubt?

Comment: I now see how this works :) Thank you so much for the help

Comment: @user544158 Fine! BTW if you are new here, take a few minutes for a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

1. $e^{1/(z-i)}=1+\frac1{z-i}+\frac1{2(z-i)^2}+\dots$ has an essential singularity at $z=i$ with residue $1$.
2. $\frac1{z+3-i}$ has a simple pole at $z=i-3$ with residue $1$.

Comment: Would you please be able to explain why hint number 1 has residue 1?

Comment: Remember that the residue at $z=i$ is the coefficient of the $\frac1{z-i}$ term in the Laurent expansion about $z=i$